# What is the ontological status of unconscious?

Tags: psychoanalysis

Has mainstream science accepted the existence of unconscious? IN PRTICULAR : Does it attribute to it any role in psychosomatic disorders?

Edit: this is the only hit I had from "the neuroscience of the unconscious" :https://mindscience.org/videos/the-neuroscience-of-the-unconscious/; but they seem to confuse here unconscious with subliminal, which is a different cup of tea.
Other 'scientific' articles often confuse unconscious with involuntary

I don't know what kind of research you expect from me, the question is :neuroscience accepts the existence and deals with 'consciousness', now, since psychoanalysis is considered as pseudoscience, what is the status of unconscious as a subject capable of influencing thoughts, specch and action of a person??

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. What has your Google searching provided? We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/987/7604 and https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/24122/7604 plus https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/24110/7604

Comment: You refer to those who **confuse** "unconscious" with something else, but you haven't even defined what "unconscious" is to you. I think the accusation of *confusion* is misplaced. For example,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscious_mind refers to "processes in the mind which occur automatically and are not available to introspection and include thought processes, memories, interests, and motivations" and "unconscious phenomena include repressed feelings, automatic skills, subliminal perceptions, and automatic reactions,[1] and possibly also complexes, hidden phobias, and desires"